I’m trying to figure out how to make a file the correct size to fit outside objects
Fairly newish, however learning very quickly.
We just upgraded to a Prusa Mini and one of the first things I wanted to print was a case for my boy's Switch game cards. I finally found the perfect one, put it into PrusaSlicer, and got ready to print only to realize I had absolutely no idea if the size this thing was printing was accurate. Well, I knew it wasn’t accurate because the box was taking up the entire bed. I came across a few other things I wanted to print to enhance other outside objects but quickly hit the same wall.
What in the world can I do to solve this?! I tried to measure the opening for the game card but I still don’t think it was measuring correctly.

If you don't have the design file (the one that was used to export the slicer file), one possibility is to print a low-quality version of the item, which you can then use to check the dimensions. Then, if adjustments are needed, you can do so using the scaling functionality of the slicer software, and if desired print another test copy. Once you're sure you've gotten the dimensions correct, you can then raise the quality of the print in your slicer software and print a final copy.

Ohhhh!! That’s a great idea! I didn’t even think about it!! Thank you!!

I also sometimes just print the first few layers of an item to verify its dimensions before committing to a full-size print.

Ahhhh. So in my case I could flip it upside down and print the top to see if the switch games would fit! THATS genius!!!
